# Overrible predefined Bash variables with arguments

Tags: bash, variables, arguments, overriding

Can someone point me out what is the problem when I want to overrible a default value in a variable with an argument in Bash? The following code doesn't work:

```
#!/bin/bash

VARIABLE1="defaultvalue1"
VARIABLE2="defaultvalue2"

# Check for first argument, if found, overrides VARIABLE1
if [ -n $1 ]; then
    VARIABLE1=$1
fi
# Check for second argument, if found, overrides VARIABLE2
if [ -n $2 ]; then
    VARIABLE2=$2
fi

echo "Var1: $VARIABLE1 ; Var2: $VARIABLE2"
```

I want to be able to do:

```
#./script.sh
Var1: defaultvalue1 ; Var2: defaultvalue2
#./script.sh override1
Var1: override1 ; Var2: defaultvalue2
#./script.sh override1 override2
Var1: override1 ; Var2: override2
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Note for the future: "doesn't work" isn't very helpful. It's better if you're specific about error messages and behavior that differs from what you expect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing the `fi` for the first `if`. But actually you're in luck: there's an easier way to do what you're doing.

```
VARIABLE1=${1:-defaultvalue1}
VARIABLE2=${2:-defaultvalue2}
```

From `man bash`:

> `${parameter:-word}`
>   **Use Default Values.** If *parameter* is unset or null, the  expansion  of  *word*  is  substituted.
>                 Otherwise, the value of *parameter* is substituted.